# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la escala del eje x de cada gráfico individualmente para cada faceta en un facet_grid en R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el número de saltos del eje x para cada gráfico individualmente para cada faceta en un facet_grid? Me gustaría modificar el eje x por separado para cada faceta. He probado con `scale_x_continuos(breaks =..., n.breaks = ...)` pero no puedo.
También he eliminado el `theme_set(theme_paleo(8))` con `theme_replace` y he probado con `theme(axis.x.text =, axis.ticks =, etc etc)` pero sin resultado positivo, alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor.

Este es el ejemplo para los diagramas estratigráficos en este enlace: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidypaleo/vignettes/strat_diagrams.html

Código:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidypaleo)
theme_set(theme_paleo(8))

data("alta_lake_geochem")

alta_lake_geochem

alta_plot <- ggplot(alta_lake_geochem, aes(x = value, y = depth)) +
  geom_lineh() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  facet_geochem_gridh(vars(param)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Depth (cm)")

alta_plot
```

Answer (score 0):

Desde `ggplot` base, no hay opción de  configurar los `breaks` de forma individual para cada faceta. Hay algunas estrategias, la ideal sería reecribir la función de facetado, en tu caso `facet_geochem_gridh()`, por ejemplo, lo que se hace en ["Modifying facet scales in ggplot2"](https://dewey.dunnington.ca/post/2018/modifying-facet-scales-in-ggplot2/) o incluso podrías investigar el paquete [`ggh4x`](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x) que cuenta con una función como `facetted_pos_scales()` que permite configurar las escalas de forma independiente. **Importante**: este paquete trabaja con objetos estándar de `ggplot` no funcionan por defecto con `facet_geochem_gridh()`, por lo que deberías usar `facet_grid()`, por ejemplo así:

```
library("ggh4x")

# Creamos una lista con las definiciones para cada una de las 6 facetas
scales <- list(
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)),
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(16, 20, 25, 30)),
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(50, 80, 110, 140, 170)),
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-30, -20, 1)),
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1,5, 1)),
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, .5, .1))
)

ggplot(alta_lake_geochem, aes(x = value, y = depth)) +
   geom_lineh() +
   geom_point() +
   facet_grid(~param, scales = "free") +
   labs(x = NULL, y = "Depth (cm)") +
   facetted_pos_scales(x = scales, y = scale_y_reverse())
```

O, de un forma bastante menos elegante, gracias a que podemos pasarle una función a `breaks`, podemos hacer que esta función varíe el retorno según el orden de ejecución ([fuente](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2019/03/07/custom-axis-breaks-on-facetted-ggplot/))

```
breaks_fun <- function(x) {
  count <- 0
  f <- function(x) {
    count <<- count + 1L
    switch(
      count,
      c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9),          # C
      NA,
      c(16, 20, 25, 30),         # C/N
      NA,
      c(50, 80, 110, 140, 170),  # Cu
      NA,
      seq(-30, -20, 1),          # d13C
      NA,
      seq(-1,5, 1),              # d13C
      NA,
      seq(0, .5, .1),            # Ti
      NA
    )
  }
  
  f
}

ggplot(alta_lake_geochem, aes(x = value, y = depth)) +
  geom_lineh() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  facet_geochem_gridh(vars(param)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Depth (cm)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_fun())
```

Por alguna razón que no quería investigar, `breaks_fun()` se ejecuta dos veces por cada faceta, la primera ejecución es la que en definitiva establece  los valores para `breaks`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar el sitio de  facet_grid, ahí hay varias opciones.
https://raymondltremblay.github.io/Visualizacion_Datos/G9_Facet_Grid.html

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]. También te recomiendo que hagas el [tour]. Una respuesta con un link no ayuda mucho

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/388946)